# Can I suppress WinDbg/dx behavior of echoing the command?

Tags: javascript, windbg

## Handling High-Frequency Breakpoints in JavaScript

I want to create a breakpoint that invokes a JavaScript function. WinDbg/dx echoes the call to that function every time the breakpoint is hit. This kills performance and readability of output.

Here's my breakpoint command.

```
> bp ucrtbase!malloc "dx @$scriptContents.OnMallocEntry(); gc"
```

When it runs, I see endless copies of

```
@$scriptContents.OnMallocEntry()
@$scriptContents.OnMallocEntry()
@$scriptContents.OnMallocEntry()
@$scriptContents.OnMallocEntry()
@$scriptContents.OnMallocEntry()
@$scriptContents.OnMallocEntry()
```

Is there some way to avoid this echoing?

- Can I invoke the function some other way besides `dx`?
- Can I suppress the echo?

Comment: try inserting -r 0 like dx -r 0 @$blah,foo()

Comment: @blabb (10.0.17134.12 X86) Nope. Out of curiosity, why might that have accomplished this? Do I need to upgrade my target platform version?

Comment: when returning some thing from a js function it used to print the Length which i suppressed by setting the Recursion Depth so thought you should give it a try 0:000> dx -r 5  @$scripts.foo.Contents.dothing()
@$scripts.foo.Contents.dothing() : hello dx

    Length           : 0x9
0:000> dx -r 0  @$scripts.foo.Contents.dothing()
@$scripts.foo.Contents.dothing() : hello dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a WinDbg Preview release in February or March with a new '-s' switch to 'dx', so you'll be able to run 'dx -s foo' to get the behavior you want.